# BadParcelableException with JobIntentService

Tags: android, jobintentservice

Using JobIntentService on Android O, getting BadParcelable Android runtime exception while trying to read an extra which is parcelable. No issues observed on < O where JobIntentService starts the service immediately

```
AndroidRuntime: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling <>
```

The classloader set for unmarshalling (setExtrasClassLoader) is default which uses BootClassLoader that is not able to find the class

Comment: Which device? Is it samsung? This is common issue on Samsung, prior ensuring that everything is ok with your code.

Comment: Its Pixel. The code works fine while using IntentService on the same device

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to help you without a [mcve]. That would include the complete Java stack trace, plus your code for working with this extra. In general, as Toe Pyae Sone Oo notes, I recommend avoiding custom `Parcelable` classes.

Comment: This issue got fixed once the class loader was set explicitly using

    intent.setExtrasClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader())

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like a issue in jobdispatcher. That stacktrace is from
Play Services and it's process which obviously can't find a that's in your
app. You should generally avoid using custom parcelables in places that
leave your process

https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html